# How to use database loaded by datatool as Tikz variable?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to read the data from a text file and use it as Tikz variable. I used datatool to import the data in overleaf, but I cannot use it in Tikz.
I would like to read path information from 'automton.txt' and use it in Tikz, so that instead of `\def\statedef{{2,0,2,5}}` I want to use `\def\statedef{{\xcor{path1},\ycor{path1},\findx{path1},\lindx{path1}}}`. Any ideas?
Also, as the text file can contain unknown number of keys, I want to iterate the text file and store all of the values before plotting them in Tikz.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{amsthm}
\pdfoutput=1
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{automata, positioning, arrows.meta,calc,cd}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}
\tikzset{
->, % makes the edges directed
>=stealth, % makes the arrow heads bold
node distance=3cm, % specifies the minimum distance between two nodes. Change if necessary.
every state/.style={thick, fill=gray!10}, % sets the properties for each ’state’ node
initial text=$ $, % sets the text that appears on the start arrow
}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\let\labelindent\relax
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{customlegend}[1][]{%
    \begingroup
    % inits/clears the lists (which might be populated from previous
    % axes):
    \pgfplots@init@cleared@structures
    \pgfplotsset{#1}%
}{%
    % draws the legend:
    \pgfplots@createlegend
    \endgroup
}%

% makes \addlegendimage available (typically only available within an
% axis environment):
\def\addlegendimage{\pgfplots@addlegendimage}
\makeatother
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[labelsep=quad,indention=10pt]{subfig}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    redfill/.code={
    \definecolor{mycolour1}{rgb}{1,0,0}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/fill=mycolour1!40}
      }
    }
    \tikzset{
    greenfill/.code={
    \definecolor{mycolour2}{rgb}{0,1,0}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/fill=mycolour2!30}
      }
    }
    \tikzset{
    bluefill/.code={
    \definecolor{mycolour3}{rgb}{0,0,1}%
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/fill=mycolour3!40}
      }
    }
    \tikzset{
    cyanfill/.code={
    \pgfkeysalso{/tikz/fill=teal!60}
      }
    }
    \tikzset{
    twocolorfill/.style n args={2}{path picture={
            \fill[#1] (path picture bounding box.south)--(path picture bounding box.north)--(path picture bounding box.north east)--(path picture bounding box.south east)--cycle;
            \fill[#2] (path picture bounding box.south)--(path picture bounding box.north)--(path picture bounding box.north west)--(path picture bounding box.south west)--cycle;
            }}
    }
    \tikzset{
    threecolorfill/.style n args={3}{path picture={
            \fill[#1] (path picture bounding box.east)--(path picture bounding box.north east)--(path picture bounding box.north west)--(path picture bounding box.west)--cycle;
            \fill[#2] (path picture bounding box.center) -- (path picture bounding box.south)  arc [start angle=-90, delta angle=-90, radius=1] -- cycle;
            \fill[#3] (path picture bounding box.center) -- (path picture bounding box.south)  arc [start angle=-90, delta angle=90, radius=1] -- cycle;
            }}
    }
    \tikzset{
    fourcolorfill/.style n args={4}{path picture={
            \fill[#1] (path picture bounding box.east)--(path picture bounding box.north east)--(path picture bounding box.north)--(path picture bounding box.center)--cycle;
            \fill[#2] (path picture bounding box.center)--(path picture bounding box.north)--(path picture bounding box.north west)--(path picture bounding box.west)--cycle;
            \fill[#3] (path picture bounding box.center)--(path picture bounding box.south)--(path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.west) -- cycle;
            \fill[#4] (path picture bounding box.center)--(path picture bounding box.south)--(path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.east) -- cycle;
            }}
    }
    \tikzset{
            colorfill1_sub/.code=
            {
            \ifnum\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/colorfill_item}=#1
            \tikzset{greenfill}
            \else
            \fi 
            },
            colorfill2_sub/.code=
            {
            \ifnum\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/colorfill_item}=#1
            \tikzset{redfill}
            \else
            \fi 
            },
            colorfill3_sub/.code=
            {
            \ifnum\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/colorfill_item}=#1
            \tikzset{bluefill}
            \else
            \fi 
            },
            colorfill4_sub/.code=
            {
            \ifnum\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/colorfill_item}=#1
            \tikzset{cyanfill}
            \else
            \fi 
            },
            hashfill1_sub/.code=
            {
            \ifnum\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/colorfill_item}=#1
            \tikzset{pattern=north west lines, pattern color=black}
            \else
            \fi 
            },
            fourcolor1_sub/.code=
            {
            \ifnum\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/colorfill_item}=#1
            \tikzset{fourcolorfill={cyanfill}{redfill}{greenfill}{blue!50}}
            \else
            \fi 
            },
            threecolor1_sub/.code=
            {
            \ifnum\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/colorfill_item}=#1
            \tikzset{threecolorfill={cyanfill}{greenfill}{blue!50}}
            \else
            \fi 
            },
            twocolor1_sub/.code=
            {
            \ifnum\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/colorfill_item}=#1
            \tikzset{twocolorfill={blue!50}{cyanfill}}
            \else
            \fi 
            },
            colorfill_item/.initial=0,
            colorfill/.code n args={9}
            {
            \tikzset{colorfill_item=#1,colorfill1_sub/.list=#2,colorfill2_sub/.list=#3,colorfill3_sub/.list=#4,colorfill4_sub/.list=#5,hashfill1_sub/.list=#6,fourcolor1_sub/.list=#7,threecolor1_sub/.list=#8,twocolor1_sub/.list=#9}
            } 
    }
\begin{filecontents*}{automaton.txt}
path1,2,0,2,5
path2,2,2,6,8
path3,2,-2,9,11
\end{filecontents*}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={thekey,v1,v2,v3,v4}]{data}{automaton.txt}
\DTLdisplaydb[noheader]{data}
\DTLgetvalue{\myb}{data}{2}{2}

\newcommand{\xcor}[1]{\DTLfetch{data}{thekey}{#1}{v1}}
\newcommand{\ycor}[1]{\DTLfetch{data}{thekey}{#1}{v2}}
\newcommand{\findx}[1]{\DTLfetch{data}{thekey}{#1}{v3}}
\newcommand{\lindx}[1]{\DTLfetch{data}{thekey}{#1}{v4}}


\xcor{path1}
\ycor{path1}
\findx{path1}
\lindx{path1}


\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=\textwidth,scale=0.8}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, on grid,>={Stealth[inset=0pt,length=6pt,angle'=28,round]}
            ]

    \begin{customlegend}[legend style={at={(10,-8)},anchor=south},legend columns=-1,legend style={column sep=1ex},legend entries={Proposed Method,PCM PTA-MPC,CB PTA-MPC,PTA-MPC,Failed State}]
    \addlegendimage{black,only marks, mark=*, cyanfill,style={scale=4}}
    \addlegendimage{black,only marks, mark=*, bluefill,style={scale=4}}
    \addlegendimage{black,only marks, mark=*, greenfill,style={scale=4}}
    \addlegendimage{black,only marks, mark=*, redfill,style={scale=4}}
    \addlegendimage{black,only marks, mark=*, pattern=north west lines, pattern color=black,style={scale=4}}
   \end{customlegend};




    %% DO NOT put extra space below!!!
    %% {first state xcoor,first state ycoor,first state superscript, last state superscript}
    %% State Definition
    \def\statedef{{2,0,2,5}}
    %% {first state superscript, last state superscript}
    %% Straight Edge Definition
    \def\straightsolidedge{{1,5}}
    \def\bendrightsolidedge{}
    \def\bendleftsolidedge{}
    %% Color Definiton
    \def\rstates{{5}}
    \def\gstates{{}}
    \def\bstates{{}}
    \def\cstates{{3}}
    \def\hashedstates{{}}
    \def\bicolorstates{{3}}
    \def\tricolorstates{{}}
    \def\quadcolorstates{{4}}

\node[state,initial,fourcolorfill={cyanfill}{redfill}{greenfill}{blue!50}](q1){$q^{1}$};
\foreach \e in \statedef
{\edef\mye{{\e}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{\mye[0]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{\mye[1]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myfirstind}{\mye[2]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mystartind}{int(\mye[2]+1)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mylastind}{\mye[3]}
\node [state, colorfill/.expanded={\myfirstind}{\gstates}{\rstates}{\bstates}{\cstates}{\hashedstates}{\quadcolorstates}{\tricolorstates}{\bicolorstates}] at (\myx,\myy) (q\myfirstind){$q^{\myfirstind}$};
\foreach \a[evaluate=\a as \b using int(\a-1)] in {\mystartind,...,\mylastind}{
\node[state, right of=q\b, colorfill/.expanded={\a}{\gstates}{\rstates}{\bstates}{\cstates}{\hashedstates}{\quadcolorstates}{\tricolorstates}{\bicolorstates}] (q\a){$q^{\a}$};
}
}

\foreach \r in \straightsolidedge
{\edef\myr{{\r}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mystartstate}{\myr[0]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myendstate}{\myr[1]-1}
\foreach \d[evaluate=\d as \e using int(\d+1)] in {\mystartstate,...,\myendstate}{
\draw (q\d) edge (q\e);
}
}

\foreach \t in \bendrightsolidedge
{\edef\myt{{\t}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\f}{\myt[0]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\g}{\myt[1]}
\draw (q\f) edge[bend right] (q\g);
}

\foreach \u in \bendleftsolidedge
{\edef\myu{{\u}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\h}{\myu[0]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\i}{\myu[1]}
\draw (q\h) edge[bend left] (q\i);
}

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{adjustbox}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```